# NGINX - Remove TLS v1.3

Tags: nginx, windows-server-2012, http-status-code-502

We are facing 502 error at our IIS web server, which used to work fine up to recently.

We had to change our reverse proxy machine: went from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 22.04, and in this proccess the NGINX version changed from 1.21.3 to 1.18.0.

Right now, with NGINX 1.18.0, the 502 occurs. At NGINX log we see:

> peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Unknown error) while SSL handshaking to upstream

The connection is being served with TLS v1.3, as informed by Mozilla Firefox 101.0.1 (64-bits).

We're working with a Windows Server 2012, which only accepts TLS up to v1.2 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-).

At upstream log there is nothing. If we go back to older NGINX the connection goes without problem (TLS is v1.2). So the problem seems to be at NGINX. We suspect it to be from TLS v1.3 (as per link provided), but couldn't manage to solve this.

We tried updating "nginx.conf" `ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1;` but it didn't work, we still get TLS v1.3. We also tried to update NGINX (`apt update` and no version change) and some settings (`proxy_ssl_name` and `proxy_ssl_server_name` and `proxy_pass`) with no success either.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: `ssl_protocols` controls the protocols for the _client_ (browser), which is not your problem. **For the backend connection use [`proxy_ssl_protocols`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_protocols)**.

Comment: PS: someone must have customized the nginx on your Ubuntu 18.04 because [the _repository_ version there is 1.14.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/nginx). In fact I'm pretty sure Ubuntu never takes nginx odd versions, which are not considered stable. If that customization included new features or behavior, they may be unavailable on 1.18.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes, good point. We hired a external partner to setup this VM. It was delivered a customized version which didn't work well: LetsEncrypt would reset conf files and some other issues. Unfortunately it only was noticed a long time after the job was done, so we had to live with that. But now we are reviewing some backlogs and this came up, we are tryng to solve it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I've tried ```proxy_ssl_protocols``` without success. I did include it at both ```nginx.conf``` and server block files. Also did a reboot but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how to solve this?

> We're working with a Windows Server 2012, which only accepts TLS up to v1.2

Yup, you identified the problem right there.
Win8 won't support TLS1.3.
Yet you have a business need to communicate over TLS1.3.
Sounds like you want to swap some portion of your deployed software stack.

You *could* revert to your old Bionic Beaver,
but you're likely better off sticking with Jammy.
Time has moved on.
You want your stack components to keep up with a changing Internet.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't figure out how to use this approach to solve our issue. We are trying to find a way to make the available resources work orderly. Replace hardware or Windows Server 2012, although desirable, is currently not possible.

Answer (score 0):

We understood that the reason for the 502 error was NGINX didn't accept a private certificate while proxying the connection (our IIS had a private certificate - locally generated).

This case was closed by removing SSL from internal segment (between nginx and IIS), while keeping SSL v1.3 from the user/client to NGINX segment.

Answer (score 0):

nginx using server, Firstly use the server then on this server and edit the, etc/nginx/nginx.conf file and go to the SSL section in this section only replace with "ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1" this line with this "ssl_protocols TLSv1.2".
Then run "systemctl restart nginx" and check our TLS version in the upgrade.